# Real time location sharing using socket.io nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to share real time location between multiple users and stored the socket id in the database and get the id from database then emit the location to specific user. It is one to one location sharing. The issue is that when the number of users increase then interaction with the database also increase which is the major drawback. Is there any other way to store the socket id in code side do not get the socket id from database every time

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: sorry i cannot show the code, it is messed up. I am just looking for expert opinion. It will be really help full if you give advise

Comment: Well hi, it's sad that u can't share, but first thing i can say that you can't trust socket.id property which created new in every connection. Is there an auth system that u use? maybe use user's actually db id's to store data?

Comment: i am using JWT with passport.

Comment: The quick solution which i find is a maintain object with key as user_id and value as socket_id and it is working fine for now and it help me reduce the calls to database as i am directly accessing the socket_id from the object and emit the data to require user. But i am still not sure whether it is authentic solution or not. I am also removing the id from the object on disconnection

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using redis for this? It's an in-memory data structure store, used as a database, cache and message broker.

Comment: Actually a already implement socket.io in the application and i am also using it for chat as well. Now the major is when location will be share asap when he move or etc it will check the database for socket id.

Comment: I saw some examples where array is maintaining with socket. When new user connects with the socket it stores the socket id in array and when it disconnects remove the value from array. That's the only solution when i find for one to one sharing